# Saxon XSLT 2.0 ignore whitespace

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I'm using text output method. And I need to ignore all whitespaces in template.

```
<xsl:template ...>
   text
</xsl:template>
```

I'm receiving in output "     text", but I need only "text".

Thanks.

Comment: Good question (+1). See my answer for the best XSLT solution and for an explanation. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> ```
> <xsl:template ...>   
>    text   
> </xsl:template>
> ```
>
> I'm receiving in output "     text",
>   but I need only "text".

**Use**:

```
<xsl:template ...> 
   <xsl:text>text</xsl:text> 
</xsl:template>
```

**Explanation**: In XSLTAny node that is not white-space-only, doesn't belong to the `"xsl namespace"` and is a child of an `<xsl:template>` is output "as-is". **[The XSLT Spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#section-Creating-Text)** specifically says:

> "A template can also contain text
>   nodes. Each text node in a template
>   remaining after whitespace has been
>   stripped as specified in [3.4
>   Whitespace Stripping] will create a
>   text node with the same string-value
>   in the result tree"

**The [`<xsl:text>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#section-Creating-Text) instruction was designed exactly with this use-case in mind**. It gives the developer control to specify exactly what text should be output.